# C++ program not running on other computers

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

A simple question, I have made a program that runs on my computer perfectly but not on someone else's computer.  This simple question is a big headache of mine. I have read at least thousands of topics on the internet.

I tried to copy msvcp90.dll and other dll files to the target machine but that didn't work. I read an article which says you have to copy a manifest file too.  Now I don't know which manifest file to copy.

I also have created my own dll file but that didn't work either.

Can anybody please help me, I'm in a big headache (I don't want to statically link the libraries, just tell me the concept of dynamic linking). Thank you.

One other thing, I have used windows.h header file in my program and a lot more header files. I am using visual studio 2008.

Comment: What .NET version are you targeting? Make sure that target machine has it.  What about processor?  Are you compiling it for 64 or 86.  Those are the kind of things you have to tell us.  Plus... what sort of error are you getting (what message is being displayed)?  From what you've told us, it's very hard to know what exactly it is that you messed up.  Is it a console application or UI.  If it's UI, what libraries are you using?

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure you are compiling the release version of your application - typical users never have the debug c-runtime installed.

Second, you probably want to install the full c-runtime library on the client machine that corresponds to the version of Visual Studio you are using.  Here's a link for the VS 2008 runtime: [C Runtime Library](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29)